# Node.js - child process with spawn: can't stream data from child

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I want to spawn a child process on windows to open a terminal (cmd.exe). I got everything working, except that i'm not able to stream data from the child process to the parent. I want to access the output from the terminal in the parent process. Here is my code:

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    var child = spawn('cmd', [ '/c', 'start'], {
        cwd: '{path-to-folder}'
        });


    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    child.on('close', function () {

        console.log('close');
    })
```

I'm really stuck so any help or tipp would be awesome!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're starting new shell in new terminal session. You can intercept output only from command that is run same terminal session.

For example, if you change `start` to `dir` you'll have output:

```
var child = spawn('cmd', [ '/c', 'dir'], {
    cwd: '.'
    });
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9401-94AE

```
Directory of C:\Temp


12/02/2015  01:29 PM    <DIR>          .
12/02/2015  01:29 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/02/2015  01:30 PM               403 test.js
               4 File(s)     10,423,442 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  12,869,840,896 bytes free

close
```